# Write to Google sheet skipping 1st row

Tags: r, googlesheets4

When using the package googlesheets4 is there any method for writing data to a sheet skipping the first row so that the data being written to a sheet starts at row 2? I am hoping to leverage something similar to when you read a sheet and utilize ex. skip = 2 to read data starting at the 3rd row

I have tried the following which does not work
`write_sheet(data = df, ss = "google_sheet_url", skip = 1, sheet = "test")`

[image: Desired output]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can call `write_sheet()` with an empty data.frame and that will create a sheet with one empty row you can then subsequently call `sheet_append()` with your actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skip=n` is only for `read_excel()`

in the `googlesheets4` library to start at a specified range, you'd use `range_write()`. This is similar to the `startRow=n` in the `xlsx` library.

```
range_write(ss = "google_sheet_url", data = df, range = "B1", sheet = "test")
```